# firebase.notifications() is throwing error in react-native-firebase

Tags: android, firebase, react-native-firebase

I have successfully integrated firebase on my mobile application. for now I am testing it on android. I am successfully receiving notification. My next step is to trigger the event when app is in foreground and in background and read the data. for this matter I saw the documentation and used `firebase.notifications().displayNotification()`. But it is throwing error.

> Ensure you have:
>
> 1) Installed the required Firebase Android SDK dependency
>   'com.google.firebase:firebase-notifications' in your
>   'android/app/build.gradle' file.
>
> 2) Imported the
>   'io.invertase.firebase.notifications.RNFirebaseNotificationsPackage'
>   module in your 'MainApplication.java' file. 3) Added the 'new
>   RNFirebaseNotificationsPackage()' line inside of the RN'getPackages()'
>   method list.

Comment: I tried doing it but there is nothing like com.google.firebase:firebase-notifications in firebase documentation.

Comment: I am already compiling compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.4' in android/app/gradle.build

Comment: Core is just for the main package, but you still need to add the other packages (e.g. Firestore, storage, messaging) as you need them in your project.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you need follow the instructions on [this page](https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/notifications/android) to install the Notifications dependency. They recently rewrote the notifications part of react-native-firebase, so this might also be needed for your use case.

Comment: Yes that was the solution. I don't know how I missed it. Thanks anyway

Comment: Android Notifications package link for version 5.x.x [https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/notifications/android](https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/notifications/android)

Comment: Updated with the 5.x link :)

Comment: @NoahAllen Hey I have same setup mentioned in doc but getting this error again and agaiN. I am using v5 of react-native-firebase.

Comment: Me too man getting the same error even though i followed that tutorial.

Comment: A ton of things were changed for version 6 of rnfirebase, so you'll likely have to update to use the new format. It looks like they are in the process of updating the notifications library: https://invertase.io/oss/react-native-firebase/releases/v6.0.0#where-is-the-notifications-library. In the meantime, make sure npm and everything else still points at v5

Comment: @NoahAllen i'm using 5.5.7 and still having this error, too bad i can't update to v6 because i need push notifications for both iOS/Android. Any idea? im super stuck, keeps throwing that error.

Comment: I'd mostly make sure your various dependencies are still on 5.5.x (including pods and the gradle files) and try to follow the instructions for that version. Not sure what else to do besides that

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error Error: You attempted to use a firebase module that's not installed on your Android project by calling firebase.notifications() using invertase firebasev6...

After a couple research I found that notification should be implementation in rnfirebase.io thats firebase v5 and lesser

So, invertase decided not to use notification in their firebase package v6.

To use notifcation u can refer to their notifee package when doc is in alpha version or you can use wix/react-native-notifications  etc... which is extra package

Comment: Can you help me now for v6 and react native v0.63.3?